# The item was deleted because it was excluded by a crawl rule

Tags: search, crawl, 2019, crawl-rules

My search crawl is not working for my local site. 
On my Crawl Log I see a warning:

> Item not crawled due to one of the following reasons: Preventive crawl rule; Specified content source hops/depth exceeded; URL has query string parameter; Required protocol handler not found; Preventive robots directive. ( **This item was deleted because it was excluded by a crawl rule.** )

Important information:

- I just moved all my content databases to a newly installed Sharepoint on a new server
- I am running Sharepoint Server 2019 Standard
- When I change the address in the content source to full FQDN, the search works partially with many 401 warnings
- The address in question is `https`
- Same address with `sps3` gets crawled successfully with no issues
- There is no robots.txt file in the site

I tried and checked everything I could think of, including:

- I checked that the default access account has access to the website
- I browsed the website ( using a browser ) while being logging in using the default access account
- I made sure there are **no crawl rules**
- I created a new crawl rule to include the affected URL
- I did "index reset"
- I disabled loopbackCheck
- I used Fiddler to monitor the traffic, the crawler is not even accessing the site

If you have any suggestions, please advice.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of trying and failing, I solved the issue by cleaning up the content databases from missing features.

I had to manually uninstall all missing features using:

```
stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id <GUID> -force
```

After doing that the crawler started crawling again. But I don't know which feature in particular was causing the issue.